# How do I avoid using Global when using a variable in a different function?

Tags: function, global-variables, global

I am building a sort of Road Code Quiz type of program that uses the user's inputs across multiple functions.

I established the variable *usernote* equal to *NONE* in my main routine, set it as *global* in my *notes()* function then updated it to equal something else, and uses it in another function called *quizfinish()*.

The idea was to have a button called a function that take the user's inputs and use it in another Tkinter window, the problem is I constantly use global to allow the program to use variables from another function. I have tried to use return and taking the variable as an argument but have failed due to my lack of coding skills.

Here is a preview of my code:

```
def notes():
global usernote
usernote = str(ent_notes.get("1.0", "end-1c")) 
lbl_notesavestatus.config(text = "Saved!")

def quizfinish():
quizending = Tk() 
quizending.title("Well done!") 
quizending.geometry("410x365")
lbl_endnotes = Label(quizending, text = usernote)
lbl_endnotes.place(x = 10, y = 190)

usernote = NONE
```

as you can see, I need to use *usernote* in *quizfinish()* but can only do (within my understanding) when I set *usernote* as a global variable, which from my understanding is not a good practice at all. Also both of these functions are not in any classes.

The code works fine currently, but how could I use *usernote* in another function without setting it as global?

Comment: The indentation in your code needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> program that uses the user's inputs across multiple functions.

> The idea was to have a button called a function that take the user's
> inputs and use it in another Tkinter window.

You have typo error `usernote = NONE`. shoudld be `usernote = None`.

The problem can be fixed.

- Avoid using `global`.
- Add assigned to `tk.StringVar()`.
- Add `Entry` widget, and add `textvariable=ent_var`.
- Add `Button` widget and add `command` keyword.
- Add parameter quizfinish(data) function.
- Replace `tK()` to `quizending = tk.Toplevel()`
- Add  `usernote` and  place `quizfinish(usernote)` inside notes function.

You can use `ent_var` for multiple functions instead of `global`.

Snippet modified:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

ent_var = tk.StringVar()

ent_notes = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=ent_var)
ent_notes.place(x=10, y=10)

lbl_notesavestatus = tk.Label(root)
lbl_notesavestatus.place(x = 10, y = 70)


def notes():     
    usernote = ent_var.get()
    print(usernote)
    lbl_notesavestatus.config(text = "Saved!")
    quizfinish(usernote)
     
def quizfinish(data):
    quizending = tk.Toplevel() 
    quizending.title("Well done!") 
    quizending.geometry("410x365")
     
    lbl_endnotes = tk.Label(quizending, text=data)
    lbl_endnotes.place(x = 10, y = 40)
     
btn = tk.Button(root, text='Click', command=notes)
btn.place(x=10, y=100)        
 
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]  [image]

[image]